# Only want to add to mysql database if publish_stream successful

Tags: mysql, facebook-php-sdk

Please can you help me. I have created a  facebook app to publish to wall and add details to mysql database but at present the user has to authenticate the app and in doing so sends blank data to the database. How can I make the database only be updated when publish rights have been given.

```
<?php
include_once("src/facebook.php"); //include facebook SDK

$config = array(
     'appId' => 'xxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxx',
    'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
  );


  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();



  $formemail = $_POST['formemail'];
  $formname = $_POST['formname'];
  $formphone = $_POST['formphone'];

  echo $email;
  echo $formname;
  echo $formemail;
  echo $formphone;

?>
<html>
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/style.css">


       <script type="text/javascript" src="jhttp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>




  <script type="text/javascript">
    opener.location.reload();
    window.close();
</script>



  <?php
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                    array(
                                      'link' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/ahora-opening-comp',
                                      'message' => 'I have just entered the competition to WIN a table for 8 at Ahora on the 28th September at O2 Accademy, Sheffield '
                                 ));


        // Give the user a logout link 
            ?>
        <!-- html POsted to wall -->

<div class="wrapper">  
<div class="container container-thanks">
<div class="thankyou">



<?php

        echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '"><img src="images/logoutfb.png"></a>';

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $email = $user_profile['email'];
        echo $email;


          //Variables for connecting to your database.
//These variable values come from your hosting account.
$hostname = "xxxxx";
$username = "xxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxx";

//These variable values need to be changed by you before deploying
$password = "xxxxx!";



$con=mysqli_connect("$hostname","$username","$password","$dbname");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO users (id ,  formname , formemail , fbemail, formphone , date)
VALUES (NULL, '$formname', '$formemail' , '$email', '$formphone' , NOW())";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.

            ?>
        <!-- html POsted to wall -->

<div class="wrapper">  
<div class="container container-share">
<div class="thankyou">

<?php

      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 
                        'display' => 'popup',
                        'scope' => 'publish_actions, email',
                        'redirect_uri' => 'http://ibizasocial.com/ahora/FBapps/fb-opening/submit.php'
                         ));

              echo '<a href="#" onclick="window.open(\''.$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('display' => 'popup', 'scope' => 'publish_actions',)).'\', \'Facebook\', \'height=400,width=600\');"><img src="images/loginfb.png"></a>';        

        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, so print a link for the user to login
      // To post to a user's wall, we need publish_actions permission
      // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
      // need to specify it here.

        ?>
        <!-- html POsted to wall -->

<div class="wrapper">  
<div class="container container-share">
<div class="thankyou">

<?php


      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 
                        'display' => 'popup',
                        'scope' => 'publish_actions, email',
                        'redirect_uri' => 'http://ibizasocial.com/ahora/FBapps/fb-opening/submit.php'
                         ));

              echo '<a href="#" onclick="window.open(\''.$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('display' => 'popup', 'scope' => 'publish_actions',)).'\', \'Facebook\', \'height=400,width=600\');"><img src="images/loginfb.png"></a>';


    } 

  ?>   

  </div></div>

  <div>
  <a href="https://www.iubenda.com/privacy-policy/429825" target="_blank">Click here to view Privarcy Policy </a></div>
  </div>   

  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: that is some very old and very bad coding. try to split your code into separate files for php, html and javascript, and get the latest php sdk for facebook. also, there is "jhttp" in the jquery include.

Comment: correct code indentation would also be nice. this is horrible to go through :(

Comment: also, there is getLoginUrl 4 times (!) in your code. you really need to clean up.

Comment: and finally, the most important thing: you are not allowed to prefill the "message" parameter with some promotional spam. it always has to be 100% user generated, and you are not allowed to prefill an input field where the user can change the message either. don´t create spam apps, and read the facebook policy ;)

Comment: thanks for your feedback - as you cab tell - new to coding apps. Have changed the message to a user input field and created a varrible to store the getLoginUrl. Any tips on how to only update database when staus update complete?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed

According to the Facebook docs, the return value is the ID of the post if it was successful, as string value.